# JRuby Warbler not creating usable executable JAR files

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, bundler, warbler

I've been trying to get a JRuby script that is very simple in nature that requires Net::SSH to perform a task on a remote computer and exit. When I issue the command `jruby testssh.rb`, the program works flawlessly, however, when I use Warbler to compile it into a JAR, I receive errors about not being able to load Net::SSH.

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

> pik use jruby-1.7.1

> jruby -S warble jar
C:/ruby/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rawr-1.7.0/lib/zip/zip.rb:28: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
rm -f test-ssh.jar
Creating test-ssh.jar

> java -jar test-ssh.jar
LoadError: no such file to load -- net/ssh
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085
  require at file:/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/jruby4935218336857439685extract/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.11.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
   (root) at test-ssh.rb:7
     load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101
   (root) at file:/C:/Users/User/Dropbox/programming/ruby/jruby/net-ssh/test-ssh/test-ssh.jar!/META-INF/main.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085
   (root) at file:/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/jruby4935218336857439685extract/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.11.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
  require at file:/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/jruby4935218336857439685extract/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.11.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
error: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- net/ssh
```

I then put the files into a gem, and added the `spec.add_runtime_dependency = "net-ssh"` to the gemspec, and:

```
require 'net/ssh'
gem "net-ssh"
```

into the Gemfile. Then when I run `jruby -S warble`, I get a different error. I also noticed, Bundler, and Ruby didn't play well with the '-' in the name, so I had to recreate the file again.

```
> jruby -S warble
C:/ruby/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rawr-1.7.0/lib/zip/zip.rb:28: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
No default executable found in test-ssh.gemspec, using bin/test-ssh.rb
rm -f test-ssh.jar
Creating test-ssh.jar

> java -jar testssh.jar
LoadError: no such file to load -- testssh/bin/testssh.rb
     load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101
   (root) at file:/C:/Users/User/Dropbox/programming/ruby/jruby/net-ssh/testssh/testssh.jar!/META-INF/main.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085
   (root) at file:/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/jruby6762643836642223701extract/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.11.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
  require at file:/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/jruby6762643836642223701extract/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.11.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
error: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- testssh/bin/testssh.rb
```

I'm at a loss for what needs to be done, and I've found a lot of half-baked answers for questions similar to this, or people who have left bugs about this on the Warbler github page for more than a year with no answers.

The Gist with the code and errors are located here: https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/10191754

---

The solution was:

The way bundler creates Ruby gems is that it utilizes Git, and I wasn't using `git add .` to include all the changed directories. Once I did `git add .` and `git commit`, Warbler picked up those directories that it was missing the first go around. Then for gem dependency, it was as simple as editing the .gemspec file, and including `runtime_dependency` for each gem that I had required into my own gem. After that, Warbler included those dependencies, and the JAR file can run without JRuby installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs some file that it can run when you run the jar!  You can specify one in the gemspec, but it will default to bin/.rb.  No such file exists, thus the error.

Comment: I see that now. I used PeaZip to open the Jar and look inside of it, and in the testssh directory, there was no bin folder. I saw I had to use the [jar utility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html) to update the jar, but I was only able to place it in the main directory, and not under the testssh directory. I need to figure out how to do that without corrupting the JAR. Is there a way to make warbler include the bin, or specify it in my gemspec?

Comment: Don't modify the jar - in the folder where you're calling warbler, add bin/testssh.rb.

Comment: I do have the bin folder in the folder that the jar is being created from. However, its not including it. Would I have to add somethign to the gemspec to make warbler include that dir?

Comment: I have to facepalm a bit now, because the reason Warbler wasn't picking up my other directories was because I didn't do a `git add .` to include the new updates to the gem. I keep forgetting that Bundler utilizes git to manage files in the gem.

Comment: I have edited/updated the answer with what I had figured out. Basically, if you write a gem as it should be normally, and use `git add .`, warbler will automatically include those files.